# Why is WinAPI's HWND_MESSAGE not a compile-time constant?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, constexpr

The following code fails to compile with Visual Studio 2022:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(){
    constexpr auto test = HWND_MESSAGE ;
}
```

The compiler output is:

```
test8.cpp(4): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
test8.cpp(4): note: failure was caused by unevaluable pointer value
test8.cpp(4): note: the call stack of the evaluation (the oldest call first) is
```

Is HWND_MESSAGE not a known value at compile time?

Comment: FWIW `HWND_MESSAGE` is a compile-time constant, namely -3. But it's casted to a HWND, which is a pointer type.

Comment: Its type is HWND, handle-to-window.  Like all winapi handles, the compiler considers it a pointer type and doesn't want to evaluate its value.  Thus "unevaluable pointer value".

Comment: Btw, best to tag such questions with [visual-c++] to avoid the unix wrath.

Comment: @HansPassant, the cause seems to be a C++ feature/limitation rather than a VC++ limitation. I tried this `constexpr auto test = (void*)-3` with other compilers and they also refuse to compile.

Comment: `constexpr` must be 100% free of Undefined Behavior. C-cast and `reinterpret_cast` are sources of UB, thus they are forbidden in `constexpr` by the C++ standard.

Comment: @273K: which doesn't mean that the compiler will report every UB that exists in constexprs.